# How to Specify Additional Parameter to AWS Lambda Function Triggered by S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, events, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am creating an AWS Lambda function that is triggered for each PUT on an S3 bucket. A separate Java application creates the S3 bucket, sets up the trigger to the Lambda on Put, and PUTs a set of files into the bucket. The Lambda function executes a compiled binary, it passes to the binary a script, which acts on the new S3 object.

All of this is working fine.

My problem is that I have a set of close to 100 different scripts, and am regularly developing new scripts. The ZIP for the Lambda contains all the scripts. Scripts correspond to different types of files, so when I run the Java application, I want to specify WHICH script in the Lambda function to use. I'm trying to avoid having to create a new Lambda for each script, since each one effectively does the exact same thing but for the name of the script.

When you INVOKE a Lambda, you can put parameters into the context. But my Lambda is triggered, so most of what I react to is in the event. I can't figure out how to communicate this simple parameter to the Lambda efficiently as I set up the S3 bucket and the event trigger.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have S3 post extra parameters to your Lambda function. What you can do is create a DynamoDB table that maps S3 buckets to scripts, or S3 prefixes to scripts, or something of the sort. Then your Lambda function can lookup that mapping before executing your script.

Comment: It's the latency & cost of that lookup I would like to avoid. I had considered prefixing the name of each object PUT to the bucket with the script name, like scriptname/objectname and parse it out that way. It just didn't seem very elegant.

Comment: Cache the map in the Lambda function so it only has to go back to DynamoDB when it encounters a lookup it hasn't performed before. If the table is small enough you could even pull down the whole table when the Lambda function is first called.

Comment: If you are in total control of the S3 PUT operations then you could add metadata to the object when it is uploaded which would indicate to your Lambda function which script to use: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html#object-metadata

Comment: I think you're onto something with this metadata. Looking at that now.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to specify parameters that are passed to the AWS Lambda function. The function is triggered by Amazon S3, which passes standard information (bucket, key).

However, when creating the object in Amazon S3 you could attach object metadata. The Lambda function could then retrieve the metadata after it has been notified of the event.

An alternate approach would be to **subscribe several Lambda functions** to the S3 bucket. The functions could look at the event and decide whether or not to process the event.

For example, if you had pictures and text files being stored, you could create one Lambda function for pictures and another for text files. Both functions would be triggered upon object creation. Each function would look at the file extension (or, if necessary, look within the object itself). If it is a filetype that is handles, then it can process the object. If it is *not* a filetype it handles, the function can simply exit. This type of check could be performed very quickly and Lambda only charges per 100ms, so the cost would be close to irrelevant.

The benefit of this approach is that you could keep your libraries separate from each other, rather than making one large Lambda package.